# flow chart diagrams : tools / best practices

Tags: flowchart

Are there any free online tools out there to make visio kind of diagrams. I would like to practice my flowchart skills. Are there any good sites or books or articles out there that discuss best practices for flowchart diagrams.

Answer (score 8):

Dia is an open source option:
http://projects.gnome.org/dia/

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Dia.  It's also cross-platform, which won me over.  Another advantage of Dia is that the diagrams are stored in compressed XML.

I had a project where I needed to diagram something in the database, and I was able to write a program to create Dia-compatible XML from the database, which saved me a HELL of a lot of typing and drawing.  I just had to reposition and resize the objects.

Answer (score 3):

Open Office includes a program called Draw which is really nice.

Comment: This is great for simple diagrams and finally something that works well and is easy to use on Linux!

Answer (score 3):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168512/best-free-professional-looking-uml-tool#168548);

Here is some:

- StarUML - http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/ (Free)
- Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems (Not free)
- [Violet](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php)
- [Umbrello UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrello_UML_Modeller)
- [ArgoUML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArgoUML)
- [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/)

Here is a complete list of over 50 UML designer (free and not) Wikipedia list:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools

Answer (score 3):

There is a great multi-platform software that for some reason no one mentions but its really worth a try:

yEd: http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.umlgraph.org/

Found no other better solution. Program your charts.
Makes beautiful sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

[lucidchart](http://www.lucidchart.com) is an online, collaborative tool with flowchart features.

Answer (score 1):

[Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) is an online flowcharthing program.

Personally I use [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org//dia/), an open source Visio kind of clone (it works under Windows, Linux and MacOSX).